# Selectively scale a variable in R

Tags: r

Suppose you have the following dataframe named `data`:

```
Country V1 V2
US      1  2
US      2  1
US      3  1
UK      1  1
UK      2  1
UK      3  3
     ...
IT      2  2
```

Now I want to scale the variables `V1` and `V2`. The first idea would be to use something like:

```
data %>%
   mutate_at(.vars = c("V1", "V2"), .funs = scale)
```

But, what if I want to perform scaling separately for each value of the `Country` variable and have the result all in one dataframe?

This is just an example and the actual data which I am not able to provide contains a lot of NA. I am worried that if I use `select` or some of the other functions the data won't be joined back properly because of NA.

Comment: If you're concerned about `NA` values you should put at least one in your sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to have as separate data.frame/tibble, then one option is `map` and store it in a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
map(c("V1", "V2"), ~ data %>%
                          select(Country, .x) %>%
                          group_by(Country)
                          scale)
```

---

Or if we need to do a `group_by`

```
data %>%
   group_by(Country) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(V1, V2), ~ c(scale(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution with `base R` (given data frame `df` as in the post)

```
res <- (r<-Reduce(rbind,lapply(split(df,df$Country), function(x) {x[-1]<-scale(x[-1]);x})))[order(as.numeric(rownames(r))),]
```

such that

```
> res
  Country  V1         V2
1      US  -1  1.1547005
2      US   0 -0.5773503
3      US   1 -0.5773503
4      UK  -1 -0.5773503
5      UK   0 -0.5773503
6      UK   1  1.1547005
7      IT NaN        NaN
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Country = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("IT", "UK", "US"), class = "factor"), V1 = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), V2 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```